# Webview doesn't display a given web page

Tags: android, webview

I want to load [this URL](http://www.molssoft.lv/akmens/) in a `webview`, but it's showing a blank, not even connection errors. However, in the phones default browser it works fine, just not in the app. Websites like google.lv or inbox.lv are displaying just fine.

I have added internet permission in manifest file.

My simple code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.molssoft.lv/akmens");
```

Even tried to convert my webpage to XHTML and removed all scripts, but still didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try custom chrome tabs?

Comment: I guess I'll have to try this, since nothing else is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using URL with `https` that require **SSL certificate** which is secure and i think you may not have configured ssl certificate for your web page, so just use only `http`.

**Try to use:**

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.molssoft.lv/akmens/");
```

Comment: Still not working. And I think the certificate is configured, since there's a green lock next to the URL and it says "safe connection".

Comment: Same as before - blank page with no errors. The app loads the top bar with the title, but noting else below it.